# Netty 4 Java 5 support?

Tags: java, netty

Netty's page says this: "No additional dependencies but JDK 1.5 (or above)", yet when I try to compile a project using Netty 4.0.18 under JDK 1.5 I get a message:

```
bad class file: [...]netty-all-4.0.18.Final.jar(io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
```

Does Netty no longer supports Java 1.5? If so, then the webpage should be updated.

Comment: I would report this to the Netty devs if I were you, apparently a class compiled for Java 6 has snuck into the release version. Either the class(es) need to be recompiled, or the documentation needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me where on the page you saw this ?

On the README.md of our github repos it says:
"JDK 5 (for 3.x) or 6 (for 4.0+) is enough to run your Netty-based application."

Comment: It is on the front page of http://netty.io/ _"No additional dependencies but JDK 1.5 (or above)"_

Answer (score 0):

The dependency required for using and compiling are different.  To compile Netty 4.0+ you need java 1.7 see [the pom.xml](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/pom.xml#L769).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Netty 4.0.18 successfully with Java8.

Comment: How is that an answer to this thread? Good for you, but the OP is using Java 5 (for whatever reason).

Comment: The point was just to reassure the questioner that it is not an inherent problem with Netty and that they can look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, but that is a comment, not an answer.